# My question was closed, why can't I see the reason why?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, closing, questions

One of my questions was closed so it's pretty probable someone flagged it beforehand.

It would be nice to get a note with the statement the user made, to see what I did wrong. The users nickname doesn't have to be connected with this note.

With access to this extra context/reason for the flag, it would help users like me make less mistakes in the future, without having to start a meta-discussion to ask about the closure.

Comment: Was it this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/general-strategies-to-avoid-game-crashes It would help if you linked it :)

Comment: Yes, but I think my question is independent of my closed question.

Comment: People should comment before they flag, but I can't imagine one of your questions being flagged. Closing and flagging isn't usually connected, if something is worthy of flagging a mod will usually delete it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're having a bit of a terminology confusion, here, and I don't blame you because it can be confusing for a new user. I'll walk through the general terminology, and review some points.

---

**Flagging** is an anonymous act used by community users to either raise a post that needs improvement, raise it for moderator attention, or mark the post as spam or rude/abusive. The latter causes a small and temporary reputation penalty as if downvoted, unless 6 are accumulated in which the post is deleted and locked and you suffer a whopping -100. If it doesn't reach 6 votes within 2 days, the flags decay and you get your reputation back, so it's generally harmless.

The latter is posted in strict confidence to moderators only, so a flagged user technically *shouldn't* be alerted of the act unless the moderator needs to specifically talk to them.

None of your posts were flagged.

---

**Closing** makes a question unable to accept new answers. Comments may be posted and existing answers may be retooled. Only questions may be closed.

Closing by the community occurs when 5 users of sufficient reputation (usually 3k) vote to do so. A close vote decays after 4 days if the question doesn't accumulate 5. Closers select from a preset collection of reasons: duplicate, not-a-real-question, subjective and argumentative, off-topic, too localized, and belongs-on-meta. The last one actually migrates the question here. Duplicate votes will **automatically generate a "possible duplicate of..." comment if the duplicate link is not already present**, so that's automatic information of close intent.

Generally good etiquette for closing is that a user who votes for things besides duplicates will add a comment explaining why they voted. **It's not necessary, but it traditionally helps, especially if the question can be retooled.**

Additionally, when you hit 250 reputation, you gain the ability to vote to close and reopen your own posts. This has a side effect of **allowing you to see current close votes on your questions**. It may take some time to reach, but that offers the general functionality that you seem to be looking for.

---

If I'm missing any further inquiries from you, I'll be happy to address them.

Comment: Thanks, this terminology was exactly my problem.

Comment: coming from a new site member i wish they would highlight this for all new members,this answered alot of questions i had,i know it's an old post but thank you : )

Answer (score 2):

It's very well possible you're question was a victim of my crusade against subjective questions, now I agree it would have been polite to post a comment on every question I voted to close, but I think there has been enough 'public' discussion on the topic to take action as I see fit.

If people disagree, than they should do as you did now: go to Meta and discuss what should be done next.

Also, as Arda Xi commented, it's unlikely it got flagged, but more likely it got discussed in the **[Gaming Chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46/gaming)**, which I recommend everyone to visit some time, to discuss the site or just hang out!